# Removing " " (empty values) from a Character of Strings

Tags: r

I have been looking around for few hours now and have not been able not remove "" from the character of strings below.

c("Final", "A", "7.43", "8.50", "15.93", "2.00", 
"1.00", "0.30", "0.37", " 7.43", " 8.50", "0.50", "0.67", " ", 
" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "B", "7.00", "3.77", "10.77", 
" 7.00", "1.67", "3.77", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ",

I have many more of these empty values in this dataset and just want to get rid of them before organizing then as a data frame like

> Final
>   A       B
>   7.43    7.43
>   8.50    8.50
>   15.93   0.50
>   2.00    0.67
>   1.00
>   0.30

Thanks,

Comment: Please `dput()` your object, it will be easier to help if we know what you're working with. But you'll probably want something like `df$A = df$A[df$A != " "]`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, @mickey. I have tried your code (as I had tried it before) and it did not help me getting rid of these " ". Getting on my nerves now!

Comment: If you tried something and it didn't work, can you show what you did, so we don't repeat it.  Try something like this: `x<-c("Final", "A"....)`; `x[x !=" "]`

Comment: Uhuuu! @Dave2e! High five buddy!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base `grep` with `values = TRUE`. That searches the character vector for a given regex pattern and returns all values where that pattern is found.

You can think about the logic of your pattern a couple ways. One might be to think of it as keeping values with a "word" character, which are letters, numbers, or underscores.

```r
x <- c("Final", "A", "7.43", "8.50", "15.93", "2.00", "1.00", "0.30", "0.37", " 7.43", " 8.50", "0.50", "0.67", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "B", "7.00", "3.77", "10.77", " 7.00", "1.67", "3.77", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ")

grep("\\w", x, value = T)
#>  [1] "Final" "A"     "7.43"  "8.50"  "15.93" "2.00"  "1.00"  "0.30" 
#>  [9] "0.37"  " 7.43" " 8.50" "0.50"  "0.67"  "B"     "7.00"  "3.77" 
#> [17] "10.77" " 7.00" "1.67"  "3.77"
```

Another way is to find values with a character that *isn't* a space (`\\S` is the negation of `\\s`):

```r
grep("\\S", x, value = T)
#>  [1] "Final" "A"     "7.43"  "8.50"  "15.93" "2.00"  "1.00"  "0.30" 
#>  [9] "0.37"  " 7.43" " 8.50" "0.50"  "0.67"  "B"     "7.00"  "3.77" 
#> [17] "10.77" " 7.00" "1.67"  "3.77"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>